# Eloquent Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, migration

I am trying to add a foreign key to the 'users' table.
These are the time stamps of the migration

[image: eloquent migrations]

And this is the code:

```
Schema::create('types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('types');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //...
        $table->integer('type')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('type')->references('id')->on('types')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I really don't know what I do wrong.

**EDIT**
Here is what happens after the suggestions which I received

[image: error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add the foreign key only **after** you created the table, i.e:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //...
        // $table->integer('type')->length(10)->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedInteger('type');       
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('type')->references('id')->on('types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

And probably its better to use `$table->unsignedInteger('type');`

**Update:**

The conclusion is that `type` is a reserverd word in MYSQL.